# RetryMiddleware not doing its thing

Tags: scrapy

I'm looking at the log of a spider that has the RetryMiddleware active:

```
[scrapy.middleware] Enabled downloader middlewares: Less

['sh_scrapy.diskquota.DiskQuotaDownloaderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'lari.downloadermiddlewares.DocumentExtraction',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
 'sh_scrapy.middlewares.HubstorageDownloaderMiddleware']
```

And a response raising a `ConnectionRefusedError` (which is included in [the ones that the RetryMiddleware should intercept](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py#L32)):

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] Error downloading <GET xxx> Less

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

but the request is not actually retried when the spider is done crawling the rest (yes, the spider finished normally, no cancellation or anything).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try different scenarios to handle this case

1. Make sure that your internet connection is proper.
2. Try different user agents.
3. Check your scrapy version.
4. Also, make sure that you are replicating the exact copy of browser request with the given URL(check for header, cookies and all).

Comment: Other than possibly 3., what does the rest have to do with the middleware not kicking in?

Comment: I was refering to the error mentioned `Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused`.